# Which network interface does my VPN use?

Tags: networking, vpn

I have both a wired (enp59s0u2u1i5) and wireless interface connected to the internet, and on top of that I use a VPN (wg-mullvad).

How do I see which of these interfaces (wired or wireless) is used by the VPN interface to route traffic through?

This is the output of `ip link`:

```
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp59s0u2u1i5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: wg-mullvad: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1380 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/none
```

Output of `netstat -r`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp59s0u2u1i5
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.64.0.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 wg-mullvad
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp59s0u2u1i5
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ip route get` with the exact parameters, i.e. the tunnel endpoint's remote IP address and importantly the fwmark that's used by wg-mullvad if one is shown by the `wg` command.

```
# wg show wg-foo
interface: wg-foo
  fwmark: 0x52
peer:
  endpoint: 1.2.3.4

# ip r get 1.2.3.4 mark 0x52
1.2.3.4 via 192.168.10.1 dev rtl0 table 82 mark 0x52
```

(You can add `fibmatch` to directly see the actual route entry that's used.)

In general, use `ip route` to list routing tables on Linux, as there could be more than one – the packet mark set by WireGuard is used with `ip rule` to select an alternative table for the encrypted traffic. You could work it out manually, but some VPN clients generate a bit complex rules and it's easier to use `ip r get` and let the kernel provide the answer.

```
# ip rule
501:    from all fwmark 0x52 lookup 82 proto static

# ip r ls table 82
default via 192.168.10.1 dev rtl0 proto dhcp
```

(But even for just the main table, I'd generally avoid `netstat -r` on Linux, because it doesn't know how to show beyond the simplest route entries.)

Don't forget that `tcpdump` can literally show you the packets being sent out through each interface.